# Invoke github composite action within same repo

Tags: github

I am defining a github action that I invoke in other repositories.
The folder structure looks like:

```
 setup-node
 └── 
    .github
    └── workflows
        └── release-management.yml
        └── validate.yml
    └── release-drafter.yml
 └── action.yaml
```

Within `action.yaml` I have:

```
name: My action
description: <Description>
inputs:
  <Some inputs>

runs:
  using: 'composite'

  steps:
  ...
```

Within `validate.yml`, I cannot invoke my action in a step:

```
 name: Invoke my action
 uses: ./action.yaml
 with:
   <My inputs>
```

However, I get the following error: `Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile'`. I am able to invoke the action from other repos successfully. Is there any way for me to invoke my action within its own repo so I can run some verification steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke your own action like so:

```
 name: Invoke my action
 uses: ./
 with:
   <My inputs>
```

This will call the action defined within the repo in your workflow.

Comment: Does this really works? I got an error `Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/opt/actions-runner/_work/repo_name/repo_name'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?`

Comment: @sasawatc It worked in my case, though the `action.yaml` file needed to be top level as in my question. You also do need to run `actions/checkout@v3` though I did omit that part in my question/answer.

Comment: How does it work when multiple actions are defined in the repo? Can I manage it somehow?